# How to use different enums types in an annotation?

Tags: java, enums

I am defining system constants of different modules using different enums specific to the module. Now I need to define an annotation in which I can specify any one of these system constants.

I cannot define the annotation, because constants of different modules have different enum types. If I define an interface that is implemented by all the enum types, that won't work, because interfaces cannot be used in annotations. I can always define String constants instead of enums. But is there a way to do this using enums?

```
interface ISystemConstant {
}

enum ModuleA implements ISystemConstant {  // Enum of system constants in ModuleA
}

enum ModuleB implements ISystemConstant {  // Enum of system constants in ModuleB
}

@interface Annotation {    // The annotation I need to define
    ISystemConstant sysConstant(); // Illegal interfaces are not allowed in annotations.
}
```

Comment: You can have two methods, one for each enum type.

Comment: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.1) says `It is a compile-time error if the return type of a method declared in an annotation type is not one of the following: a primitive type, String, Class, any parameterized invocation of Class, an enum type (§8.9), an annotation type, or an array type (§10) whose element type is one of the preceding types.`

Comment: @peter That won't be possible, i have around 10-15 enums across different modules.

Answer (score 3):

- **Use a proxy enum**

You can then use the type of the proxy in your annotation. Here's a little example:

```
public @interface Annotation {
    Types value();
}

interface Type {}

enum FirstType implements Type {
    ONE, TWO;
}

enum SecondType implements Type {
    A, B
}

// proxy
enum Types {
    FT_ONE(FirstType.ONE),
    FT_TWO(FirstType.TWO),
    ST_A(SecondType.A),
    ST_B(SecondType.B);

    private final Type actual;

    private Types(Type actual) {
        this.actual = actual;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return actual;
    }
}
```

- **Use a string as identifier**

Use a string to identify the desired enum. You would have to check at runtime if it is valid.
You could also add a second field `Class<?> type()` where the used modul is specified.

```
public @interface Annotation {
    String value();
}
```

Comment: That would be equivalent to define all the constants in one enum.

Comment: Not exactly. The enums are stronger typed this way. But I don't know if that is any worth, since I don't know your usecase.

Comment: This would be difficult to manage and there will be extra overhead of re-writing the same constant twice.

Comment: I updated the answer with another option. ...You will have some kind of overhead, since you need a workaround.